# Abstracting out common rspec functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pundit

In a large number of our controller tests we must stub out pundit policy functionality like so:

```
policy = double("policy", :show? => true)
allow(UserPolicy).to receive(:new).and_return(policy)
```

My goal was to end up with something like `allow_policy(UserPolicy).to(:show?)` instead which reads much easier.

In order to accomplish this I wrote this little module which I included in my spec.

```
module PolicyFaker
  def allow_policy(policy)
    fake_policy = FakedPolicy.new
    fake_policy.policy = policy
    fake_policy
  end

  class FakedPolicy
    attr_accessor :policy

    def to(action)
      policy = double("policy", action => true)
      allow(policy).to receive(:new).and_return(policy)
    end

    def not_to(action)
      policy = double("policy", action => false)
      allow(policy).to receive(:new).and_return(policy)
    end

    def to_not(action)
      not_to(action)
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use `double` or `allow` outside of a describe block and so this module does not work.

How can I accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the module via [rspec configure](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module)?

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include PolicyFaker
end
```

If I remember correctly, `allow_policy` will be available and property scoped if you do it that way.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that, but `allow` `receive` and other rspec functionality was still not available within PolicyFaker